# How to send video to multiple TVs over the network

Tags: video, networking

I'm working for a company with multiple buildings. On each building there are some smart TVs connected to the wired network. Is it possible to share HD videos from a computer to all the TVs?

## What I have now

I have created a mini website to show the videos with javascript for the loop. Works well. But every day we need to open the browser to load the website. Can I load the browser on startup?

## Some considerations

- TV model: Sony kdl-70w855b. If necessary, we can change to LG with webOS.
- Videos must be on a loop (no audio needed)
- If possible, nobody has to touch the TVs. We have on/off timer.
- We have DLNA.
- It's not necessary to be in real-time.
- I can set up windows/linux servers.
- I can't set up a computer/player for every TV.
- Chromecast allowed.
- I have to use the wired network. No a/v wires allowed.

Can you recommend some software/service to do this?

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you and sorry for my English :)

Comment: Sorry, wrong language. "bucle" is the spanish word for "loop". I have updated the question.

Comment: Windows has a **Start up** group on the start menu or HKEY_LOCAL_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run and add an entry under there and the App specified will Auto launch

Comment: Cybernard, thank you. But I was talking about the web browser starting up on the TV, not the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) has a wide number of streaming modes, including streaming to multiple destinations - you will need to read the [chapters on streaming](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/index.html) and experiment a little.

- Cross Platform so you could use a dedicated linux machine as a server.
- Free.
- Can broadcast media (several methods).
- Can be set to loop.
- Lots of online help.